# Can we use sqlite3 for django in production azure

Tags: python, django, database

i have developed a django app in my local pc using sqlite3 server and after hosting it on azure app service. Every time i push new version it overwrite database and static files what should be the best and free fix for this.

Expecting solution and suggestions

Comment: Sorry. Can you elaborate a bit on the `overwrite` problem? Do you make any changes on the DB locally and do not want to push in the server?

Comment: changes on server got overwritten by data in local machine after push

Comment: Could it be that you have a database migration in your azure pipeline?

Comment: Ok, what I did before is `git stash` -> `git pull` -> `git stash pop`. (make sure only sqlite & static files are changed)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use azure blob services : https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/azure.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use the gitignore file to prevent the database and static files from uploading and overwriting the current database in your host.

Comment: than they just got deleted on server

Comment: migrate your models on the server and you don't have to worry about it again